# Files are shown in the wrong dropzone when using clickable option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have multiple dropzones on a page.

For each dropzone I want to be able to trigger each dropzone two ways:

```
1: by clicking in the dropzone element
2: by clicking an upload button just above the dropzone element
```

So I found the `clickable` option, with the following description from the dropzone website:

```
If true, the dropzone element itself will be clickable, if false nothing will be clickable.
You can also pass an HTML element, a CSS selector (for multiple elements) or an array of those. In that case, all of those elements will trigger an upload when clicked.
```

So in my options I added:

```
clickable: ".uploadbutton, .dropzoneform",
```

But this gives a bug. When clicking any dropzone, the image (or preview of the image) is always shown in the first dropzone. Also a window to choose a new file immediately opens without clicking a second time.

When I remove the `clickable` option from my dropzone code, all works fine but the button doesn't trigger the upload, only clicking in the dropzone element which is the default setting.

How can I make both elements trigger the option to choose a file without above bugs?

This is my entire dropzone code:

```
$('.dropzone').each(function(index){
    $maxfiles = $(this).attr('maxfiles');
    $inputquantity = $(this).find('input').val();
    $thisdropzone = $(this);
    $(this).dropzone({
        clickable: ".uploadbutton, .dropzoneform",
        paramName: 'postedFile',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictDefaultMessage: '<i class="fas fa-file-upload uploadicon"></i> <span class="uploadtxt">Upload je bestand(en)</span>',
        dictRemoveFile: 'Verwijder',
        dictCancelUpload: 'Annuleren',
        dictInvalidFileType: 'Dit type bestand is niet toegestaan',
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation: 'Weet je zeker dat je het uploaden wilt annuleren?',
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Maximale aantal bestanden overschreden',
        maxFiles: $maxfiles,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .tif, .tiff',
        thumbnailWidth: '205',
        thumbnailHeight: '140',
        thumbnailMethod: 'crop',
        previewTemplate: $(".hiddendiv").html(),
        sending: function (file) {

        },
        // File contains dropzone file object, response contains ajax response from php file
        success: function (file, response) {

        },
    })
});
```

This is my HTML markup, this example contains two dropzone elements which have the above mentiones bugs:

```
<table class="table upload-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="plantmore-product-thumbnail uploadimg" width="100">
            <a href=""><img src="assets/images/noimg.jpg" alt=""></a>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-name" width="200">
            <div class="prodinfocheckout">
               <a class="prodname" href="">
               Monomeer
               </a>
               <span id="togglespecscheckout" class="prodspecscheckout noselect">
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> Specificaties
               </span>
               <div class="togglespecscheckout">
                  Hoogte : 20cm
                  <br>
                  Breedte : 20cm
                  <br>
                  uploaden : 1
                  <br>
                  Lijmlaag : Wit
                  <br>
                  Laminaat : Anti-slip laminaat
                  <br>
                  Afwerking : Contoursnijden
                  <br>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="190">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">
            Benodigd formaat:<br>
            <span class="benodigd">20 x 20cm</span>
            </span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="185">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Benodigde aantal<br> bestanden: <span class="benodigd">10</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Bestanden <br>toegewezen: <span class="benodigd">0 / 10</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" valign="top">
            <button class="uploadbutton btn yellowbtn dz-clickable">Bestand(en) uploaden</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="newrow">
         <td colspan="6">
            <form action="upload/uploaden.php" class="dropzone dropzoneform dz-clickable" maxfiles="10" id="dropzone1">
               <input type="hidden" value="Monomeer" name="productnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="Twan" name="klantnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="20" name="hoogte">
               <input type="hidden" value="20" name="breedte">
               <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span><i class="fas fa-file-upload uploadicon"></i> <span class="uploadtxt">Upload je bestand(en)</span></span></div>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="plantmore-product-thumbnail uploadimg" width="100">
            <a href=""><img src="assets/images/noimg.jpg" alt=""></a>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-name" width="200">
            <div class="prodinfocheckout">
               <a class="prodname" href="">
               Monomeer
               </a>
               <span id="togglespecscheckout" class="prodspecscheckout noselect">
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> Specificaties
               </span>
               <div class="togglespecscheckout">
                  Hoogte : 90cm
                  <br>
                  Breedte : 90cm
                  <br>
                  uploaden : 1
                  <br>
                  Lijmlaag : Wit
                  <br>
                  Laminaat : Anti-slip laminaat
                  <br>
                  Afwerking : Contoursnijden
                  <br>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="190">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">
            Benodigd formaat:<br>
            <span class="benodigd">90 x 90cm</span>
            </span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="185">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Benodigde aantal<br> bestanden: <span class="benodigd">1</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Bestanden <br>toegewezen: <span class="benodigd">0 / 1</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" valign="top">
            <button class="uploadbutton btn yellowbtn dz-clickable">Bestand(en) uploaden</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="newrow">
         <td colspan="6">
            <form action="upload/uploaden.php" class="dropzone dropzoneform dz-clickable" maxfiles="1" id="dropzone4">
               <input type="hidden" value="Monomeer" name="productnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="Twan" name="klantnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="90" name="hoogte">
               <input type="hidden" value="90" name="breedte">
               <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span><i class="fas fa-file-upload uploadicon"></i> <span class="uploadtxt">Upload je bestand(en)</span></span></div>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Maybe I can use `clickable` in another way? Does anyone know why those bugs are there?

Comment: Not used DropZone myself but reading this documentation - https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-clickable - I would perhaps suggest passing an array with the 2 values to the .clickable =  clickable: [".uploadbutton", ".dropzoneform"]

Comment: @InchHigh I tried that but it has the same result as just adding two classes after the option.